# Ignored records rows in PHP to MSSQL connection

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I have a problem with a different result, when asking mssql for data with this query. Executed directly on server it gives me 3 results, but in connection from PHP server it gives me just one row = 041SE010-0240
propabli is problem with enconding but I dont know how to solve that I tried change encoding for connection from PHP server. I have tries CP1250, CP1251 encoding on server is CP1250 and collate Czech_CI_AS.

```
SELECT S.IDS, S.RefStruct, ISNULL(S.StavZ - S.ObjedP, 0) AS quantity
            FROM SKz S
            WHERE S.IDS IN ('092COž01', '00XXž004', '041SE010-0240')  AND RefStruct IN (2, 3)
```

My code:

```
$where = '';
    if (!empty($this->allowedWarhouses)) {
        $where = ' AND RefStruct IN (' . implode(', ', $this->allowedWarhouses) . ')';
    }

$resource = $this->pohodaDatabase->query(
    "SELECT S.IDS, S.RefStruct, ISNULL(S.StavZ - S.ObjedP, 0) AS quantity
    FROM SKz S
    WHERE S.IDS IN ('092COž01', '00XXž004', '041SE010-0240')" . $where
);
$productStocksDataWrapper = array();
var_dump($this->pohodaDatabase->rows($resource));  // int(0)
var_dump($this->pohodaDatabase->getLastQuery()); //SELECT S.IDS,S.RefStruct,ISNULL(S.StavZ - S.ObjedP, 0) AS quantity FROM SKz S WHERE S.IDS IN ('092COž01', '00XXž004', '041SE010-0240') //
while ($row = $this->pohodaDatabase->fetch_assoc($resource)) {
    var_dump($row); // only 041SE010-0240
    $productStocksData = new PohodaProductStocksData();
    $productStocksData
        ->setCatnum($row['IDS'])
        ->setPohodaWarhouseExtId($row['RefStruct'])
        ->setQuantity($row['quantity']);
    $productStocksDataWrapper[] = $productStocksData;
}
var_dump($productStocksDataWrapper); // just 041SE010-0240
die();
```

Comment: Show us PHP code

Comment: What driver do you use to connect to SQL Server and what is your table definition?. Thanks.

Comment: You've indicated that the query produces the expected results when you execute it manually, so how exactly have you confirmed that the problem is this query itself and not the PHP code?  How are you actually observing the problem?

Comment: I observe is problem in PHP (in setting of connection to database) because two same Query have different result in same DB environment

Comment: I using sqlsrv php extension for connect mssql server

Comment: In your PHP you are concatenating part of your query, `$where`, we don't know what this is.

Comment: added but it's not source of issue

Comment: @KubaDolníček Aren't you asking _us_ where the source of the issue is? If you know where the issue is, why don't you say so in your question? You really need to give us all of the information to diagnose your issue, every update you make you leave something out. What is the value of `$this->allowedWarhouses`? If your query isn't returning the same data, then it's not the same query.

Comment: $this->pohodaDatabase->getLastQuery() -> gives U last executed query.. and that query giving me ```SELECT S.IDS,S.RefStruct,ISNULL(S.StavZ - S.ObjedP, 0) AS quantity FROM SKz S WHERE S.IDS IN ('092COž01', '00XXž004', '041SE010-0240')``` and if I executed that in the console it gives me diferent result. 
$this->allowedWarhouses is setting witch is also stored in database and for getting that data there is whole datamapper and It's not necessary I think dont get me wrong I am glad about for giving me some your time on my issue but giving you all dependencies to variables is not necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iconv('UTF-8', 'cp1250', `QUERY STRING...`);

THAT WAS A SOLUTIONS POINTLESS PIECE OF SHIETS.

Answer (score -2):

```
$resource = $this->pohodaDatabase->query(
            "SELECT S.IDS, S.RefStruct, ISNULL(S.StavZ - S.ObjedP, 0) AS quantity
            FROM SKz S
            WHERE S.IDS IN ('092COž01', '00XXž004', '041SE010-0240')" . $where
        );

        $productStocksDataWrapper = array();
        var_dump($this->pohodaDatabase->rows($resource));  // int(0)
        var_dump($this->pohodaDatabase->getLastQuery()); //SELECT S.IDS,S.RefStruct, ISNULL(S.StavZ - S.ObjedP, 0) AS quantity
            FROM SKz S
            WHERE S.IDS IN ('092COž01', '00XXž004', '041SE010-0240') //
        while ($row = $this->pohodaDatabase->fetch_assoc($resource)) {
            var_dump($row); // only 041SE010-0240
            $productStocksData = new PohodaProductStocksData();
            $productStocksData
                ->setCatnum($row['IDS'])
                ->setPohodaWarhouseExtId($row['RefStruct'])
                ->setQuantity($row['quantity']);

            $productStocksDataWrapper[] = $productStocksData;
        }

        var_dump($productStocksDataWrapper); // just 041SE010-0240
        die();
```